# Firebase Crashlytics: Is it possible to have the crashes from multiple apps combined in one overview?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

With Fabric it used to be possible to have multiple apps with the same code base and 'base' package name combined in one crash overview. I can't seem to figure out if this is possible as well with Firebase Crashlytics.

So what I mean is:
I have multiple variations of an app. 
Say with package names:

```
com.norakomi.appname.app1
com.norakomi.appname.app2
com.norakomi.appname.app3
```

etc.

I want all the crash reports combined in one overview, since they are using the same code base and I don't want to navigate every time through all the (say) 30 versions of the app.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Indeed the Fabric API provides the kits's method appIdentifier("parent app identifier") which can be used to aggregate several apps under one parent app. It might be worth requesting the equivalent method to the Firebase Crashlytics team...

Comment: If you have a different bundle identifiers, even in Fabric they should not report to the exact same Crashlytics page - every time you send a build and run event with a Fabric API key, and Crashlytics hasn't seen an app with that exact bundle ID, it will onboard a new app into your organization for that bundle ID. By "same code base" do you mean these apps are targets for the same project? In general, if the bundle ID is different, the crash reports associated will have to go to a different view. And integrating with BigQuery on Firebase will allow you to combine crash report datasets.

Comment: In Fabric.Builder there is an appIdentifier() method that allows you to set the identifer to, say, com.norakomi.appname.app1 for all of your apps. Is there a way to do this in the new Firebase Crashlytics?